# Java listener for textfield

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java and I'm kinda playing with the stuff, and I got a problem about textfield listener. What I'm doing wrong ?

intr. variables are strings with the correct answers.
scor's initial value is 0.

The problem is that when I input the correct answers, my result is still 0.

```
final String raspunsul1 = rasp1.getText();
    final String raspunsul2 = rasp2.getText();
    final String raspunsul3 = rasp3.getText();
    final String raspunsul4 = rasp4.getText();

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Trimite raspunsurile");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (raspunsul1.equals(intr1)){
                scor = scor+25;

            }

            if (raspunsul2.equals(intr2)){
                scor = scor+25;
            }

            if (raspunsul3.equals(intr3)){
                scor = scor+25;

            }

            if (raspunsul4.equals(intr4)){
                scor = scor+25;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Felicitari, ai obtinut " + scor + " puncte!");

        }
```

Comment: First, I don't see any listener to your `textField`. Second, which value/result are you talking about ?

Comment: you are not reading textfield's value on button click

Comment: With the code you've posted, I believe the issue is what Jigar Joshi suggests: you read the "input" from textfields on initializing the form, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, Jigar Joshi, this was the problem!